# Ember.js - Index route vs. "top-level" resource route?

Tags: ember.js

When creating a "standard" crud resource in Ember.js, what is the difference between the index route and the "main" route?

For example, a users resource:

```
// app.router.js

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', function() {
      this.route('new');
      this.route('show', { path: '/:user_id'});
      this.route('edit', { path: '/:user_id/edit'});
    });
});
```

Which route should contain the following "main" model hook?

```
// app/routes/users/index.js OR app/routes/users.js?

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});
```

In other words, should I use the UsersRoute or the UsersIndexRoute?  I find this very confusing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should put a model hook to `UsersRoute` route if a given model is required to render all of the nested routes, i.e. `index`, `new`, `edit` and `show`, as it will be invoked when entering any of these routes.

If the model is required only when rendering `/` route, an not `/:user_id` routes, then it should be loaded in `UsersIndexRoute` route.

See [JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/setavo/1/) for an example of when model hooks nested routes are being triggered.

For your use-case, it could be either way - if you would like to have *master-child* type of UI where list of users is rendered also when editing/showing/adding user, you should load and render list of users in `UsersRoute`, and then just render additional content in the nested route; if instead you do not want to render list of user in nested routes, just load and render them in `UsersIndexRoute`.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you!  Related question if you don't mind:  Do I need the top level Users template in both cases or only with a master-child type of UI?

Comment: np; You do not need top-level users template (or route) explicitly defined, Ember creates them automatically if you do not define them; see updated [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/setavo/3/edit).